# Java::ANT create Jar

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am trying to create Jar file using ANT.
I have couple of java-classes inside folder named My-Classes.
I also have 1 Jar files inside that folder My-Classes (ABC.jar).

I want to include all classes from folder My-Classes in newly created jar. Along with that I want to include only 2 classes which are present in ABC.jar, in my newly create Jar file

Note Abc.jar has many classes inside it.

I simply want ANT to scan JAR file & include only 2 specified class files in newly created JAR.

Currently it only include classes from com/mypackage/testApp/ package

```
<jar jarfile=${dist.lib}/test/testApp.jar>
  <fileset dir=My-Classes includes=com/mypackage/testApp/**/>
  <fileset dir=My-Classes includes=com/abc/Bundle.class,com/abc/Work.class/>
</jar>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `zipfileset` rather than a plain `fileset` to extract entries from one JAR and add them to another.

```
<jar destfile="${dist.lib}/test/testApp.jar">
  <!-- all .class files from under the My-Classes directory -->
  <fileset dir="My-Classes" includes="**/*.class" />
  <!-- two specific classes from out of My-Classes/ABC.jar -->
  <zipfileset src="My-Classes/ABC.jar"
              includes="com/abc/Bundle.class,com/abc/Work.class" />
</jar>
```